# Is there a way to position a div directly in the center of it's parent?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a div called `#text`, inside another div `#box`. Right now I've tried to center `#text` by doing this:

```
#box {
  width: 50%;
  #text {position: relative; margin-left: 48%;}
}
```

This code puts `#text` approximately in the center of `#box`, but when I resize the screen, the size of `#text` changes relative to the size of the screen, so the size of its `margin-right` changes, and it is no longer exactly in the center.

I've heard there is a "hack" for this involving a few wrapper divs, but I don't want to overcomplicate my css or html. Is there a simple way to horizontally position a div exactly in the center of its parent?

Comment: Does `#test` have a width defined?

Comment: If #text has a width you can give it this style which should centre it within its parent -  margin:0 auto;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

Using [flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) is IMO the best way to center child horizontaly and verticaly. Its [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) is good.

Answer (score 1):

First off the CSS you posted is not valid. You can accomplish what you are looking for with something like this:

CSS

```
body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#box {
    width:100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: lightblue
}
#test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="test">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

[See the JS.Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf6a3uqt/1/)

Comment: Like Leo mentions in the comments the margin: 0 auto is the key for the centering

Answer (score 1):

use `margin: 0 auto;` in the css of #text

Answer (score 1):

You want exact center of page, regardless of content?  Do something like this:

```
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Relative to the parent, set the following attribute on the container for your element:

```
div.containerOfPs {
  position: relative;
}
```